# PanZoomBar is not constructor and GetFeatureInfo error using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geoserver

I’m having trouble with my OpenLayers code displaying PostGIS data in GeoServer

Why would this line (also PanZoomBar) map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scale'))); Produce this error in FF error consol

Scale / PanZoomBar  is not a constructor

Also the GetFeatureInfo code is only returning one feature is this because the way I’ve constructed the layers

This is just a template, and once I’ve worked out all the glitches, I’ll be creating a perl script to build this page on the fly each time it loads will be unique based upon how many layers/ VIEWPARAMS the user wishes to view at once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers/theme/default/style.css"/>
        <!-- Basic CSS definitions -->
        <style type="text/css">
            /* General settings */
            body {
                font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: small;
            }
            /* Toolbar styles */
            #toolbar {
                position: relative;
                padding-bottom: 0.5em;
                display: none;
            }

            #toolbar ul {
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #toolbar ul li {
                float: left;
                padding-right: 1em;
                padding-bottom: 0.5em;
            }

            #toolbar ul li a {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: smaller;
                vertical-align: middle;
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            #toolbar ul li a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            #toolbar ul li * {
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            /* The map and the location bar */
            #map {
                clear: both;
                position: relative;
                width: 512px;
                height: 430px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            #wrapper {
                width: 512px;
            }

            #location {
                float: right;
            }

            #options {
                position: absolute;
                left: 13px;
                top: 7px;
                z-index: 3000;
            }

            /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */
            table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-size: 90%;
                padding: .2em .1em;
            }

            table.featureInfo th {
                padding: .2em .2em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: bold;
                background: #eee;
            }

            table.featureInfo td {
                background: #fff;
            }

            table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
                background: #eee;
            }

            table.featureInfo caption {
                text-align: left;
                font-size: 100%;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: .2em .2em;
            }
        </style>
    <script src="openlayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
            // make OL compute scale according to WMS spec
            OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 25.4 / 0.28;

        var map;
        function init(){
        format = 'image/png';
            var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                    12.52, 51.72,
                    14.4, 54
                );
                var options = {
                    controls: [],
                    //'PanZoomBar', 'Navigation', 'Scale', 'MousePosition'
                    maxExtent: bounds,
                    maxResolution: 0.00365234375,
                    projection: "EPSG:4326",
                    units: 'degrees'
                };
                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);

                //
            
            var Base = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Land",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {LAYERS: 'cite:land',
                 format: 'image/png',
                 isBaseLayer: true,
/*                 buffer: 0,
                  displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                  isBaseLayer: true,*/
                  srsName: 'EPSG:4326',
                  //yx : {'EPSG:4326' : true}
                }
            );

            var L49470 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "49470",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                VIEWPARAMS: 'kathy:49470',
                LAYERS: 'cite:Q_Results',
                transparent: 'true',
                isBaseLayer: false
                }
            );


            var L10654 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "10654",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                VIEWPARAMS: 'kathy:10654',
                LAYERS: 'cite:Q_Results',
                transparent: 'true',
                isBaseLayer: false
                }
            );


            var L44670 = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "44670",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                VIEWPARAMS: 'kathy:44670',
                LAYERS: 'cite:Q_Results',
                transparent: 'true',
                isBaseLayer: false
                }
            );
            //var Qbox = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT().read(POLYGON((13.305833 52.547778,13.440556 52.547778,13.440556 52.491389,13.305833 52.491389)));
             var Qbox = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Qbox",
                "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                VIEWPARAMS: 'holly:1',
                LAYERS: 'cite:Q_box',
                transparent: 'true',
                isBaseLayer: false
                }
            );


            map.addLayers([Base, L49470, L10654, L44670, Qbox]);
            // build up all controls


                // build up all controls
              map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({
                    position: new OpenLayers.Pixel(2, 15)
                }));
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Scale($('scale')));
 
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({element: $('location')}));
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('layerswitcher')}));
           //map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

            map.zoomToExtent(
                new OpenLayers.Bounds(12.996, 52.172,13.931, 52.958)
            );


                // support GetFeatureInfo
                map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
                    document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
                    var params = {
                        REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                        EXCEPTIONS: "application/vnd.ogc.se_xml",
                        BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                        SERVICE: "WMS",
                        INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',
                        QUERY_LAYERS: map.layers[0,1,2,3].params.LAYERS,
                        FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                        Viewparams: 'kathy:49470',
                        VIEWPARAMS: 'kathy:10654',
                        VIEWPARAMS: 'kathy:44670',
                        Layers: 'cite:Q_Results',
                        WIDTH: map.size.w,
                        HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                        format: format,
                        styles: map.layers[0].params.STYLES,
                        srs: map.layers[0].params.SRS};

                    // handle the wms 1.3 vs wms 1.1 madness
                    if(map.layers[0].params.VERSION == "1.3.0") {
                        params.version = "1.3.0";
                        params.j = e.xy.x;
                        params.i = e.xy.y;
                    } else {
                        params.version = "1.1.1";
                        params.x = e.xy.x;
                        params.y = e.xy.y;
                    }

                    // merge filters
                    if(map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER != null) {
                        params.cql_filter = map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER;
                    }
                    if(map.layers[0].params.FILTER != null) {
                        params.filter = map.layers[0].params.FILTER;
                    }
                    if(map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID) {
                        params.featureid = map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID;
                    }
                    OpenLayers.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);
                    OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
                });
        }// end init
                // sets the HTML provided into the nodelist element
        function setHTML(response){
            document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = response.responseText;
        };

        
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="init()">
    <h3>OpenLayers PostGis Layers</h3>
    <DIV id=layerswitcher class=olControlLayerSwitcher></DIV>
    <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="location">location</div>
        <div id="scale">        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nodelist">
        <em>Click on the map to get feature info</em>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of OpenLayers shipped in GeoServer by default is a stripped down version of a quite old release. So change

```
  <script src="openlayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>
```

to point to a recent OpenLayers build that you can download from [openlayers.org](http://openlayers.org/) - try not to overwrite the existing version of OpenLayers as this can stop the layer previews from working.

The getFeatureInfo issue is that line:

```
QUERY_LAYERS: map.layers[0,1,2,3].params.LAYERS,
```

is wrong. JavaScript arrays don't work that way try something like:

```
QUERY_LAYERS: map.layers[0].params.LAYERS,map.layers[1].params.LAYERS,map.layers[2].params.LAYERS,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
window.onload=function(){ init(); }
```

instead of `body onload=init()`, because `window.onload` waits until all resources has loaded. `Onload` triggers when the html (without resources) has loaded.